# state does not update using useContext even if works in another app

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

Im trying to build an application where I am using useState and then passing it using context. But whenever I try onCLick increment it doesnot work. state update does not happen.

Here is the state fucntion code,

```
import { createContext, useReducer, useState } from "react";
import { DOG_ACTION } from "../utilities/app-utilities";
import { dogList } from "../utilities/dogList";

export const DogContext = createContext();

export const DogProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [dogs, setDogs] = useState(dogList);

    const dogActions = (action, payload) => {
        switch (action) {
            case DOG_ACTION.ADD_DOG: {
                setDogs((value) => {
                    value.map((item) => {
                        if (item.id == payload) item.amount += 1;
                    });
                    return value;
                });
                return 0;
            }

            case DOG_ACTION.MINUS_DOG: {
                setDogs((prev) => {
                    return prev.map((item) => {
                        if (item.id == payload) {
                            item.amount -= 1;
                            console.log(item.amount);
                        }
                        return item;
                    });
                });
                console.log("MINUS");
                return 0;
            }

            default:
                return 0;
        }
    };

    return (
        <DogContext.Provider value={{ dogs, dogActions }}>
            {children}
        </DogContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Here is the App,js,

```
import { LoggedInProvider } from "./hooks/logged-in-hook";
import { OverLayProvider } from "./hooks/overlay-hook";
import { Hero } from "./pages/Hero";
import { DogProvider } from "./hooks/dog-hook";

function App() {
    // console.log("App Level- DIST");
    return (
        <DogProvider>
            <LoggedInProvider>
                <OverLayProvider>
                    <div className="App">
                        <Hero />
                    </div>
                </OverLayProvider>
            </LoggedInProvider>
        </DogProvider>
    );
}

export default App;
```

And lastly here is the element where I need to use onCLick,

```
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import { DogContext } from "../hooks/dog-hook";
import { DOG_ACTION } from "../utilities/app-utilities";

export const DogCard = ({ name, breed, speciality, amount, image, id }) => {
    const action = useContext(DogContext).dogActions;

    return (
        <div className="flex flex-col items-start rounded-lg bg-slate-900 p-6 shadow-xl">
            <div className="flex w-full flex-row items-center justify-between">
                <button
                    onClick={() => {
                        action(DOG_ACTION.MINUS_DOG, id);
                    }}
                    className="flex flex-row items-center space-x-2 rounded-full bg-slate-700 px-4 py-2 text-white hover:bg-slate-800">
                    <img
                        src="https://cdn-icons-png.flaticon.com/512/9513/9513736.png"
                        alt="paw"
                        className="w-4"
                    />
                    <p className="text-sm">Add to Cart</p>
                </button>
                <div className="rounded-xl bg-slate-700 px-4 py-2 text-sm text-white">
                    :<span className="text-orange-500"> {amount}</span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className="mt-8 flex w-full flex-row space-x-10">
                <div>
                    <img
                        src={require(`./../images/dog-images/${image}.jpg`)}
                        alt="sample"
                        className="h-fit w-32 rounded-l-lg"
                    />
                </div>
                <div className="flex flex-col text-white">
                    <h3 className="pb-8 text-3xl font-bold text-slate-200">{name}</h3>
                    <p>
                        <span className="text-gray-400">Breed:</span> {breed}
                    </p>
                    <p>
                        <span className="text-gray-400">Origin:</span> {speciality}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

It works when I created a dummy array to taste in some other app. But not with this one. Even though everything is similar.